# Best way to extend Android api classes like EditText or View and add helper methods?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I've mostly been working with Swift programming and would often find it helpful to make extensions to add helpers to objects defined by the api like views,  edittext, ect... what is the best way to get similar extensions to Android objects in Java?  Do I have to create a custom class and use it everywhere instead of the base class?

Comment: If you come from Swift you'd be way more comfortable working with Kotlin. You can add extension functions just as easily as in Swift.
With Java you need to create a custom class and extend the base class as you said